# can't sign in Visual Studio ultimate 2013 after installing update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've installed update 3 of visual studio ultimate 2013 but after installing the problem I'm facing is, I can't sign in any more. I clicked on 'Sign in' several times but not working. There is a caution symbol on the left side of 'Sign in' text.

Comment: Have you managed to fix this?

Comment: I had to reinstall to fix the problem..even repairing couldn't solve the problem